# Node JS Nested Functions And Variable Scope

Tags: mysql, node.js, scope

Is there a way to pass the variables down to a nested callback without passing them to each function along the way unnecessarily? The problem is that I need to call getValueFromTable1 to get one value of the database. Take that result and add another variable from the original list and send that to a getValueFromTable2 to get the second piece of information from the database, and then finally take that result2 with the userID from the top level function and use that to do a DB insert.

I know I could do a more complex DB query with joins and such so that I get all my information at once and then just call one function, but my "getValueFromTable1" and "getValueFromTable2" are generic functions that get a set of data from the database that I can reuse in more than one place hence why I am trying to do it this way.

The problem I get is that node JS doesn't have the itemList in scope when i call

```
itemList[i].item2
```

And I am not passing item2 into function2 because function2 does not need it for its own purpose and it would make it take a variable it doesn't need.

```
doDatabaseInsert(itemList, userID) {

  for(var i=0; i < itemList.length; i++) {

    getValueFromTable1(itemList[i].item1, function(results) {

      getValueFromTable2(results, itemList[i].item2, function(results2) {

        //Finally do stuff with all the information
        //Do DB insert statement with userID, and results2 into table 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with a regular for loop because you are referencing `i` from inside an asynchronous callback, where the value of `i` is already `itemList.length` because the for loop finished long ago.

Try this instead:

```
itemList.forEach(function(item) {

  getValueFromTable1(item.item1, function(results) {

    getValueFromTable2(results, item.item2, function(results2) {

      //Finally do stuff with all the information
      //Do DB insert statement with userID, and results2 into table 3
    });
  });
});
```